# Excel VBA find string in row

Tags: excel, find, vba

I have a table with contactdetails (in each row the first column represents the name of the contact) and I have a Textbox in which the user is supposed to fill in the name of a contact. Now i want to make a "Register" button to register on another sheet the name of the contact as it is found in the table containing all the details.

This button should find the user input string in the table of contact details and output the name of the matching contact in a given cell on another sheet.

I have found several methods of doing this but none of them seem to work with partially matching results (For example, user inputs "John", but the name in the list is "Jr. John")

What is the best apporoach to do this using VBA in Excel?

Comment: I down voted because there appears to be a lack of research. Take a look at the `Range.Find` method, specifically the `LookAt` argument. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Answer (score 0):

You could use Instr to check for partial matches. For example, if the user input is "John" and one of the cells in the list had "Jr. John" in it this would find it.

```
Sub SearchNames()

    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = ThisWorkbook

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = book.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim firstNamesRng As Range
    Set firstNamesRng = sheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

    Dim userInputString As String
    userInputString = TextBox1.Value 'Passes the name entered by the user to the string

    Dim loopingCell As Range
    For Each loopingCell In firstNamesRng 'Loops through each cell in given range

        If InStr(loopingCell, userInputString) > 0 Then 'If Instr doesn't return "0" then do stuff

            Debug.Print "Found: " & loopingCell.Value

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

You can find more information on how the instr function works here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function